# How do I enable recording option in the BigBlueButton module?

Tags: 6

I am using the [BigBlueButton](https://www.drupal.org/project/bbb) module for conference in Drupal 6. I also installed the server.

The demo code (http://demo.bigbluebutton.org/demo/demo10.jsp) is properly executed. I passed `record=true` in my API.

How do I enable recording option in the BigBlueButton module?

Comment: Is this a question about code you wrote? If so, where is your code?

Comment: I am using drupal module and `record=true` passed in api(bbb.module) file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is resolved. I have pass `record=true` in setting array of `bbb.module` file. Please see below code

```
function bbb_init_meeting($node = NULL, $params = array()) {
  $welcome     = variable_get('bbb_content_type_welcome_'     . $node->type, '');
  $dialNumber  = variable_get('bbb_content_type_dialNumber_'  . $node->type, '');
  $moderatorPW = variable_get('bbb_content_type_moderatorPW_' . $node->type, '');
  $attendeePW  = variable_get('bbb_content_type_attendeePW_'  . $node->type, '');
  $logoutURL   = variable_get('bbb_content_type_logoutURL_'   . $node->type, '');
  $settings = array(
    'nid'          => $node->nid,
    'name'         => $node->title,
    'meetingID'    => bbb_create_meeting_id($node->nid),
    'attendeePW'   => !empty($attendeePW) ? $attendeePW : user_password(),
    'moderatorPW'  => !empty($moderatorPW) ? $moderatorPW : user_password(),
    'welcome'      => !empty($welcome) ? $welcome : t('Welcome to @title', array('@title' => $node->title)),
    'dialNumber'   => $dialNumber  ? $dialNumber  : NULL,
    // TODO: This is limited to 90000 voice bridges and may
    // collide sooner, as rand() may return x twice in a row
    'voiceBridge'  => rand(10000, 99999),
    'logoutURL'    => $logoutURL, //TODO: make absolute, as soon as supported
    'initialized'  => 0,
    'created'      => time(),
    'record' => 'true', 
    'duration' => '10',  
  );
  $params = array_merge($params, $settings);
  return $params;
}
```